# Need an SQL to create a View

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-view

I have an table in a oracle database like that:

```
   id | name      | value
   -----------------------
   1  | dog name  | ham
   1  | cat name  | miau
   1  | childs    | 1
   2  | dog name  | wham
   2  | cat name  | meow
   2  | childs    | 3
```

and I want to make a view like this:

```
 id  |  dog name | cat name | childs
------------------------------------
  1  |  ham      | miau     | 1
  2  |  wham     | meow     | 3
```

can you help me with the sql to do that please?

Comment: See [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-pivot-097235.html) how pivoting works in Oracle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this query: I was unable to connect to `SQLfiddler`. So, do check the code and tell me what it returned.

```
select *
from
(
    SELECT id, name, value FROM table A)
    pivot
    (
        max(value) for name in ('dog name', 'cat name', 'childs')
    )
order by id
```

You can learn more about PIVOT for oracle from here: [link](http://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/pivot-and-unpivot-operators-11gr1.php)

Comment: That is not valid for Oracle (`[dog name]` is an invalid identifier in SQL)

Comment: See [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-pivot-097235.html) for correct syntax.

Comment: changed the query. Recheck it.

Comment: I wrote 
select * from
(SELECT id, name, value FROM ELO_DOCUMENT_META)
    pivot
    (max(value) for name in ('ID_PL', 'CNPCUI'))
order by id

but I get an ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Comment: It was an old Oracle database. PIVOT works on databases with Oracle >= 11g.

Answer (score 3):

```
    CREATE TABLE #temp
    (
    id INT,
    name VARCHAR(20),
    value VARCHAR(10)

    )

    INSERT INTO #temp VALUES(  1,'dog name','ham')
    INSERT INTO #temp VALUES( 1,'cat name' ,'miau')
    INSERT INTO #temp VALUES(   1,'childs',' 1')
    INSERT INTO #temp VALUES(   2,'dog name','wham')
    INSERT INTO #temp VALUES(   2 ,'cat name','meow')
    INSERT INTO #temp VALUES(   2,'childs','3')



    SELECT * FROM #temp 

    PIVOT (MAX(value) FOR name IN ([dog name],[cat name],[childs])) AS PVT



     DROP TABLE #temp
```

The Solution is

```
   SELECT * FROM #temp 

    PIVOT (MAX(value) FOR name IN ([dog name],[cat name],[childs])) AS PVT
```

Replace

> "#temp" with your table name

Comment: `2  | chinds    | 3` spelling mistake change it to childs

Comment: I've edited my answer. I created the temp table to explain what he should do.